# What does the following instruction mean ---> ADD.D F4,F0,F2

Tags: assembly, cpu-architecture

What does the following instruction mean  ---> ADD.D F4,F0,F2 ;
Can someone explain what it does>

Comment: How are people supposed to answer this without you mentioning *which* assembly language you're talking about?

Comment: What assembly language? Have you consulted the processor manual? That should explain.

Comment: Lets say 80x86. This code from the book --> Computer Architecture: A Quantitative Approach, Hennesey & Patterson

Comment: You can't say "Let's say 80x86." That's like saying "What does 'Lorem ipsum' mean?" and when somebody asks, "What language is that?" you respond, "Let's say French." If you don't know the language, you can't translate it. Oh, and it says right there on the page what language it is. "... translate the above segment to MIPS assembly language" at the top of the page. The sentence immediately before the instruction says "The straightforward MIPS code... looks like this:". And Appendix B explains the instruction set. Page B-39 explains the floating point instructions. Downvoted for laziness.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That isn't X86, probably MIPS64.  The .D means double precision floating point.

```
ADD.D F4,F0,F2
```

Means add the contents of floating registers F0 and F2 as double precision floating point numbers and store the result into register F4.

http://www.tik.ee.ethz.ch/education/lectures/TI1/materials/assemblylanguageprogdoc.pdf

[image]

Comment: Thank You amdn. How did you identified the language?

Comment: I wrote microcode for X86 for 10 years. We started by using a MIPS processor and morphed it into an X86.  The microcode syntax was very much like MIPS because of the origins of the design.

Comment: The language is also identified in the textbook many times, including twice on the page you copied this instruction from.